# Android - Draw a Cylinder

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL and I already have everything up and running. I can plot triangles and other shapes but now I need to make a tube. It doesnt need to hollow(if it makes it easier).

Something like this: [Image of the cilinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuVlK.png)

How can I define a cilinder in a 3D? I think I need x,y,z and Radius. Can someone give me ideas where to start? Thank you.

Draw a triangle code:

```
 class Triangle {

 private final String vertexShaderCode =
         // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
         // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
         "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                 "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                 // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                 // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                 "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                 "}";

 // Use to access and set the view transformation
 private int mMVPMatrixHandle;


 private final String fragmentShaderCode =
         "precision mediump float;" +
                 "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                 "}";

 // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
 static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
 static float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
         0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, // top
         -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, // bottom left
         0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f  // bottom right
 };

 // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
 float color[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };


 private final int mProgram;

private short[] indices = {0,1,2,0,2,3};

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

 public Triangle() {

     // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
     ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
             // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
             triangleCoords.length * 4);
     // use the device hardware's native byte order
     bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

     // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
     vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
     // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
     vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
     // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
     vertexBuffer.position(0);

     int vertexShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
             vertexShaderCode);
     int fragmentShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
             fragmentShaderCode);

     // create empty OpenGL ES Program
     mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

     // add the vertex shader to program
     GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

     // add the fragment shader to program
     GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

     // creates OpenGL ES program executables
     GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
 }

 private int mPositionHandle;
 private int mColorHandle;

 private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
 private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

 public void drawMatrix(float[] mvpMatrix) { // pass in the calculated transformation matrix


     // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
     GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

     // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
     mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

     // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
     GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

     // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
     GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
             GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
             vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

     // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
     mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

     // Set color for drawing the triangle
     GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

     // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
     mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

     // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
     GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

     // Draw the triangle
     GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

     // Disable vertex array
     GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how you define it internally, you still have to provide a set of triangles, lines or points for OpenGL ES.
So you would need to define two equal regular polygons that lay on parallel planes. The more vertices they have the coser they will be to the circles. You can see this yourself with the formula:
[image: Formula should be here]
`R` is a radius of circumscribed circle, `r` is a radius of inscribed circle, `n` is anumber of vertices. The closer `r` is to `R` the closer the polygon is to the circle. So, the polygon will appear more like a circle if you use more vertices: when `n→∞`, `π/n→0`, `cos(π/n)→1` so `r→R`.

You could divide the polygon in different ways. For example, like this:

[image: polygon with the point in the center]

This way you'll have `n` triangles.

Or you could go this way:

[image: another way]

This way you will have `n-2` triangles.

There could be better ways, search for them on the net.